# redux-form-material-ui for react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

So I've implemented [redux-form](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form) in my react native application and it works fine. Now, Client has asked if we could change normal field to material-ui [like this](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.4/examples/material-ui/), I tried implementing [redux-form-material-ui](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form) in my react native application but it doesn't work. Here is the error which i got while running my application.

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `material-ui/Toggle` from `node_modules/redux-form-material-ui/lib/Toggle.js`: material-ui/Toggle could not be found within the project.
```

This is my package.Json

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.15",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.2",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "^4.3.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

So, My question is can we implement `redux-form-material-ui` for `React-Native` or it is limited to `reactjs`. if yes then can anyone tell what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

redux-form-material-ui has not been updated in a very long time and Toggle is not supported.

Comment: So what is the other option then?